# foreach function accessing multiple variables

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach

I am using Laravel, and I have a foreach function like this

```
$name = person::find(1);
foreach($name as $dbitems)  {
            $person->services()->updateOrCreate([
                'service' => $dbitems->Name,
                'time' => $dbitems->Time
                'price' => $anotherarrayhere
                ]);
        }
```

In the place of **$anotherarrayhere**, I want to get this array from the outside of foreach function.

```
$anotherarrayhere = $peopleserviceprice[]
```

How can I include the $anotherarrayhere variable in the above foreach function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foreach` is not a function, you can use variables from outside the loop without problems. Maybe you're confused with collection callbacks that needs to specific tell variables

Any way, you're iterating over a model, not a collection, since you're using find.

```
$person = person::find(1);
$person->services()->updateOrCreate([
    'service' => $person->name,
    'time' => $person->time
    'price' => $anotherarrayhere
]);
```